# Proof that the series $\sum^\infty_{n=2} \frac{2}{n^{2}\ln{n}}$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How can I formally proof that the series $\sum^\infty_{n=2} \frac{2}{n^{2}\ln{n}}$ converges?

I am thinking along the lines that because $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{2}{n^{2}}$ by the p-series test, then $\sum^\infty_{n=2} \frac{2}{n^{2}\ln{n}}$ must also converge because the fractions I'll be adding would be even smaller. I need to be more formal about it and prove it via some test.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^\alpha \ln^\beta (n)} $ for nonnegative $\alpha$ and $\beta$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267697/convergence-of-sum-limits-n-2-infty-frac1n-alpha-ln-beta-n-for)

Answer (score 7):

For all $n \ge 2$, we have

$$\ln{n} \ge \frac{1}{2}$$

Hence

$$\frac{2}{n^2 \ln{n}} = \frac{2}{n^2} \frac{1}{\ln{n}} \le \frac{2}{n^2} \frac{2}{1} = \frac{4}{n^2}$$

But then we have

$$\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} \frac{4}{n^2}$$ converges, since it's a multiple of a $p$-series with $p > 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Use this good fact that if $$\lim_{n\to\infty}~n^pu_n=A$$ and  $p>1$ and $A$ is finite. Here $p=2$.

Comment: And  have you also a great day my dear bro :-) +1

Answer (score 1):

The only test you need
is that if
$0 < a_n < b_n$
and
$\sum b_n$ converges
then
$\sum a_n$ converges.

Set
$a_n = \frac{2}{n^2 \ln n}$
and
$b_n = \frac{2}{n^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Probably overkill, but notice $a(2^n) = \frac{1}{\ln 2  n 2^{2n -1}} \leq \frac{1}{2^{2n -1}}$. So RHS is a geometric series, by comparison test, it converges.