# Convergence: $\sum\frac1{n\ln(n^3)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How do you test the convergence of

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n\ln(n^3)}$$

I tried using limit comparison test, but had no conclusion.

Comment: Do you mean to take the series?

Comment: yes, I mean to take the series. I don't know how to put the symbol sorry

Comment: Use `\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}` (or whatever limits you need).

Comment: @Isaac: What was the point of changing the correct $\ln$ to the less readable $ln$ and making a meaningless change in the coding for the fraction?

Comment: Well how does $\text{log}(\text{log}(x))$ behave as $x \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I thought this was a maths site, not a typographical inquisition. My edit may have been pointless, yet I think it contributed considerably more than the comment you left below it.

Comment: @Isaac: It defaced the previous edit and added nothing positive. It appears to have been made simply to make an edit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^\alpha \ln^\beta (n)} $ for nonnegative $\alpha$ and $\beta$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267697/convergence-of-sum-limits-n-2-infty-frac1n-alpha-ln-beta-n-for)

Answer (score 4):

If you mean the series $$\sum_{n\ge 2}\frac1{n\ln n^3}\;,$$ note that $$\frac1{n\ln n^3}=\frac1{3n\ln n}\;,$$ and use the integral test.

Answer (score 0):

Use Cauchy's test, that is $\sum_{n \geq 2} \frac{2^n}{2^n \ln(2^{3n})} = \sum_{n \geq 2} \frac{1}{3n}$

The RHS diverges.