# convergence of $\sum^\infty_{k=1} \frac {\ln(k)}{k^p}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

> For what values of p does $\sum^\infty_{k=1} \frac {\ln(k)}{k^p}$
>   converge?

Here is my work:

$\ln (k) < k$ on $[1,\infty)$ so $\frac {\ln (k)}{k^p} < \frac {k}{k^p}$

Therefore,
$ \sum^\infty_{k=1} \frac {k}{k^p} = \sum^\infty_{k=1} \frac {1}{k^{p-1}} $

This converges for $p>2$ so the original sum must converge for $p>2$ as well. Now, how do I find when this infinite sum diverges?

Comment: One can do better. There is convergence if $p\gt 1$ and divergence otherwise.

Comment: @AndréNicolas why is the sum convergent at $p=1$?

Comment: It is not convergent for $p=1$, the comment said we have convergence for $p\gt 1$ and divergence otherwise. The otherwise includes $p=1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas oh, ok..

Comment: This is the derivative of the [Riemann $\zeta$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function).

Comment: @Lucian so what?

Comment: @TanMath: the derivative of $\zeta$ function IS a function too... so it representation as a series converges, i.e., if a series converges it represent a function (if Im not wrong).

Comment: @Masacroso but I must use the four series tests: ratio, root, limit comparison, and comparison tests

Comment: I know @TanMath... I was trying to explain the comment of Lucian... What I said is so advanced for you surely

Comment: @Masacroso no I understand, but I cannot do it that way...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^\alpha \ln^\beta (n)} $ for nonnegative $\alpha$ and $\beta$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267697/convergence-of-sum-limits-n-2-infty-frac1n-alpha-ln-beta-n-for)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have divergence if $p\le 1$, by comparison with $\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{k}$.

We have convergence if $p\gt 1$. One way to do it is to let $p=1+d$, and do a limit comparison with $\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{k^{1+d/2}}$. The key fact is that $\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{\ln k}{k^{d/2}}=0$.

**Added:** We do some of the details of showing that the series converges if $p\gt 1$. Call our series $\sum_1^\infty a_k$. Let $p=1+d$. Let $b_k=\frac{1}{k^{1+d/2}}$.

The series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k$ converges. We show that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ converges by Limit Comparison with $\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k$.  We have
$$\frac{a_k}{b_k}=\frac{\ln k}{k^{1+d}}\cdot k^{1+d/2}=\frac{\ln k}{k^{d/2}}.$$
But by L'Hospital's Rule, or otherwise, $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln x}{x^{d/2}}=0$, so by Limit Comparison $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ converges.

More informally, the $\frac{1}{k^{d/2}}$ part of $\frac{1}{k^{1+d}}$ was used to "kill" the $\ln k$ (in the long run). What remains, namely $\frac{1}{k^{1+d/2}}$, decays fast enough to ensure convergence.

If you prefer, you can prove the convergence when $p\gt 1$ by using the Cauchy Condensation Test.

Comment: Can you please add more steps?

Comment: Also, I don't see how $\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{\ln k}{k^{d/2}}=0$ connects with $\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{k^{1+d/2}}$

Comment: I will, if they are still needed, but only quite a bit later. Two reasons: (i) you might as well have a try and (ii) I am about to go out  to eat.

Comment: About your second comment, in the limit comparison we will be using $\frac{\ln k}{k^{1+d}}=\frac{1}{k^{1+d/2}}\cdot \frac{\log k}{k^{d/2}}$.

Comment: "We do some of the details of showing that the series converges if $p\gt 0$" do you mean $p\gt1$?

Comment: I certainly do mean $p\gt 1$! Thanks for spotting it.

Comment: and is it 1+(d/2), not (1+d)/2?

Comment: It is $1+(d/2)$, which is the usual meaning of $1+d/2$. I decided not to write $k^{1+\frac{d}{2}}$ because that sometimes becomes illegible on small screens.

Answer (score 1):

By L'Hospital's Rule, for any $\epsilon>0$
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln{x}}{x^{\epsilon}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{\epsilon x^{\epsilon}}=0
$$
So $\ln{x}=o(x^{\epsilon})$.

For any $p>1$, let $\epsilon=\dfrac{p-1}{2}$. So
$$
\epsilon>0\hspace{ 5mm} \text{and} \hspace{ 5mm} p-\epsilon=\dfrac{p+1}{2}>1
$$
So
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln{n}}{n^p}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln{n}}{n^{\epsilon}n^{p-\epsilon}}<\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{p-\epsilon}}<\infty
$$
For $p\leqslant 1$
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln{n}}{n^p}>\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}=\infty
$$

Comment: line 4, how do you know there is an $\epsilon > 0$, I cant understand taht

Comment: I fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need L'Hospital's rule to know $\ln x=o(x^\varepsilon)$ for all $\varepsilon$: this is a basic fact in Asymptotic Analysis.

Comment: @Bernard, I just prove it in an easy way. $\ln{x}=o(x^ε)$ is not obvious. Of course there are other ways to do it.