# How to tell if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\ln(n)}{n^2}$ converges using Integral Test?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

So I have this problem:

Determine whether or not the following infinite series converge or diverge. State what test you used.

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\ln(n)}{n^2}$$

So I decided to do the Integral Test for $$\int^\infty_1\frac{ln(n)}{n^2}dx$$

I made $u = \ln(n)$ and $du = \frac{1}{n}dx$ and got:

$$\int^\infty_1\frac{u}{n}*du$$

which would become:

$$u[\ln(n)]|^\infty_1$$

This is incomplete, but does this look right so far? If not, how do I fix it?

Comment: Be careful. Your integrand should be a function of $x$.

Comment: When you tried to integrate after using a $u$ substitution., you left both $u$'s and $n$'s in the expression and chose to ignore one (*and even integrated with respect to the wrong term*).  This should not be done.

Comment: You should find if you are more careful that the integral is equal to exactly $1$.  Try integrating by parts.

Comment: Recall that when you make a change of variables in the integrand, you also have to change the limits of integration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^\alpha \ln^\beta (n)} $ for nonnegative $\alpha$ and $\beta$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267697/convergence-of-sum-limits-n-2-infty-frac1n-alpha-ln-beta-n-for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By integral test we should obtain

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{\ln x}{x^2} dx=\left[-\frac{1+\log x}{x}\right]_1^\infty$$

or by $\ln x=u \implies \frac1x dx=du$

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{u}{e^u} du=\left[-\frac{u+1}{e^u}\right]_0^\infty$$

If you are not forced to use integral test, as an effective alternative, we can use limit comparison test with

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^p}$$

with $p>1$ such that

$$\frac{\frac{ln(n)}{n^2}}{\frac{1}{n^p}}\to 0$$

Answer (score -1):

Since

$\begin{array}\\
\ln(n)
&=\int_1^n \frac{dt}{t}\\
&<\int_1^n \frac{dt}{t^{1/2}}\\
&=\int_1^n t^{-1/2}dt\\
&=2t^{1/2}|_1^n\\
&<2n^{1/2}\\
\end{array}
$,

$\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n^2}
\lt \dfrac{2n^{1/2}}{n^2}
= 2\dfrac1{n^{3/2}}
$
and the sum of this converges
by the integral test.

This can be modified
to show that
$\sum \frac{\ln(n)}{n^{1+c}}
$
converges for any $c > 0$.
Of course the sum diverges
for $c = 0$.

Answer (score -1):

Denote $$x_n=\frac{\ln n}{n^2},~~~y_n=\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}.$$We have $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{x_n}{y_n}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln n}{n^{1/2}}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\dfrac{1}{n}}{\dfrac{1}{2}n^{-1/2}}=2\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n^{1/2}}=0.$$
Notice that $\sum y_n$ is convergent. By the comparison test of the limit form, $\sum x_n$ is also convergent.